# Getting a blank page from reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, components

The following code snippets are giving me this error.

```
Line 2:10:  'navBar' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

What am I doing wrong?

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { navBar } from './components/navBar'

const App = () => {
  return (
      <navBar/>
  )
}

export default App
```

navBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";
const navBar= () =>{
  return (
  <div>
    <li>
      <Link to="/">Dogs</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/cats">Cats</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/sheeps">Sheeps</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/goats">Goats</Link>
    </li>
  </div>
  );
}
export default navBar
```

Comment: Other than `navBar` being an invalid React component name, it should be PascalCased (*i.e. `NavBar`*) it's clearly imported and used, so perhaps the issue is elsewhere and this is just the error popping out. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Link>` component is supposed to be used inside `BrowserRouter`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Dogs</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/cats">Cats</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/sheeps">Sheeps</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/goats">Goats</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a React component, the component's name MUST start with an upper case letter.

If you used `export default`  then no need to use `{}`
just import without {} and use it

`import NavBar from './components/NavBar'`

Answer (score 0):

Because you use export default, you should fix to

```
import navBar from './components/NavBar'
```

And named follow coding convention navBar to NavBar.

Comment: I've tried it, still giving the same error

Comment: @AshishKumar This worked for me. Please named correctly with coding convention . https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-roentgen-9pvh46?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I updated it to be NavBar

Comment: So using camelCase gives errors too? it works when i change it to NavBar...

Comment: PascalCase hehe . That's fine, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

React is a one page framework so you need to change your components as dynamically, use react router for this. if you need handle page as public access you can use **Nextjs**. it have a inbuild file based routing

important : Nextjs have server side rendering  so be careful  about that when you build dynamically data update